# Keep Object In Memory Between Requests with SailsJS/ Express

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm building a server using **SailsJS** (a framework built on top of Express) and I need to keep an object in memory between requests. I would like to do this because loading it to/ from a database is taking way too long. Any ideas how I could do this?

Here's my code:

```
var params = req.params.all();

Network.findOne({ id: params.id }, function(err, network) {
  if(network) {
    var synapticNetwork = synaptic.Network.fromJSON(network.jsonValue);
    if(synapticNetwork) { ...
```

Specifically, the `fromJSON()` function takes way too long and I would rather keep the `synapticNetwork` object in memory while the server is running (aka. load it when the server starts and just save periodically).

Comment: Have you looked at any caching library?

Comment: No I have not, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Any caching library would do the job, just google for them and pick one that suites you best. The easiest way is to assign your object to a global variable and access it (ideally move it to a separate module and require it anywhere you need)

Comment: I found node-cache, this seems like it could work. Do you have any examples of this being done? Also you should answer the question so that I can give you a vote up and a checkmark

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are plenty libraries out there for caching purposes, one of which is [`node-cache`](https://github.com/ptarjan/node-cache) as you've mentioned. All of them share similar api :

```
var cache = require('memory-cache');

// now just use the cache

cache.put('foo', 'bar');
console.log(cache.get('foo'))
```

You can also implement your own module and just require it wherever you need:

```
var cache = {};

module.exports = {
    put: function(key, item) {
        cache[key] = item;
    },
    get: function(key) {
        return cache[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `service` in services directory suffice for this?

Comment: @rahulserver that's what the second solution is about

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of potential solutions. The first and most obvious one is using some session middleware for express. Most web frameworks should have some sort of session solution.

https://github.com/expressjs/session

---

The next option would be to use a caching utility like what Vsevolod suggested. It accomplishes pretty much the same thing as session, except if the data needs to be tied to a user/session then you'll have to store some kind of identifier in the session and use that to retrieve from the cache. Which I think is a bit redundant if that's your use-case.

There are also utilities that will expand your session middle-ware and persist objects in session to a database or other kinds of data stores, so that session information isn't lost even after server restarts. You still get the speed of an in-memory store, but backed by a database in case the in-memory store gets blown away.

---

Another option is to use [Redis](http://redis.io/). You still have to serialize/deserialize your objects, but Redis is an in-memory data store and is super quick to write to and read from.