# Can sails JS services (in api/services directory) be used to preserve objects across requests

Tags: node.js, twitter, sails.js

A controller loses its state across requests. But can we use services to keep objects across requests?

My use case is this: I have to maintain a pool of twitter streams(via some library like npm [twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter))
On hitting a controller, a user initiates a stream. I would like to maintain a pool of all streams somewhere. Services directory looks like the proper place to put those streams(in an array).

Then on hitting another controller, i would like to fetch the appropriate stream from that array and destroy that so that it stops the streaming api.

So is service folder good for it? or do I need to use some caching library as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29173660/1291122)?

**EDIT**:

The twitter stream represent active and persistent connection to twitter apis. So I don't think they can be stored in db(or cached into secondary memory).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use any `require` able module this way, sort of treating it like an instance of an OOP class with public getters and setters in `module.exports`.

Say you have a service called `myService.js`:

```
var pool = []; // this will be initialized when the app starts

module.exports = {
    addToPool: function(obj) {
        pool.push(obj);
    },

    getPool: function() {
        return pool;
    } 
};
```

Then any controller (etc) could access the pool:

```
var myserv = require('myService');
myserv.addToPool({'one': 'two'});
var pool = myserv.getPool();
```

HOWEVER,

I have never used active memory to store things this way. How big is your pool going to get? Are you sure you don't want to do this through a database?

One other caution, I'm not positive there won't be some interference, ex `pool` being iterated over by one method initiated by one user, and being altered by another method initiated by another user, etc.

Comment: In my case, I have to store twitter stream objects. I don't think they can be stored in DB. They represent persistent connection to twitter api.

Comment: Two thoughts: one is that if you dig into the stream objects, maybe they just contain session data (etc) that would be suitable for db storage... maybe. Second, you should "gaurd" your pool variable well. Copy it before read access, and use try/catch around write access and try to handle errors smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, and Services is the right place for it, because Services in SailS is a place for logic that you need to use in many places. But I need to advise you to not do it this way! Instead, a more stateless approach can be made: Data is stored only in the database, then states can be derived from data from the DB + input from your user. This way you can scale you server without any problems:

Let's say that I have one instance of my Sails app on `server A`. Then I launch `server B` to keep up the demand. `Server A` WILL NOT share variables with `server B`, but they can share a database! And a SQL DB can provide some security for concurrency and other problems, but REDIS should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if you read my use case, I can not use DB to store twitter streams(or any object)

Comment: Actually there is nothing there about a DB... You should take a look at REDIS (https://redis.io/). It is better than just a var in your app.